# Detecting momentum/inertia scroll on iPad on page elements

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, momentum

I am building an infinite scroll component for a web page that needs to work on iPad.

So - when the user scrolls to the bottom of a list, we load more content and display an animated ajax loader image while it's loading.

I have managed to get this to work to a point by using the touchmove event to measure page scroll position and load content when required. But - when we are scrolling the page, any animated gifs (or css animated icons) stop animating (presumably to reduce load on the gpu).

I have however found a way around this - if I create an element with overflow:scroll on it, I can put all my contents in that and emply the same method of measuring position on touchmove but the animated gifs still continue to animate and I can run javascript functions in the background as well.

But - I also want the scrolling region to have the standard iOS momentum/inertia slow down after scrolling. I have managed to achieve this by applying -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to the scroll region.

So - to my question - when I release the scroll element and it gradually slows down, I would like to measure the position of the scrolled element as it auto slows down (if that makes sense). I can measure it as I scroll through the use of the "touchmove" event and I can measure it when the momentum comes to a halt but not during the momentum/slow-down bit.

I can run javascript loops/intervals while it is happening but it seems impossible to acually measure the scroll position of the element as it gradually slows down.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have an answer to your question but I noticed you said you can get the position when the momentum scroll comes to a halt after it finishes slowing down. Could you please explain how you do this as I am trying to achieve this myself.

Comment: Hi - I'd need to dig out the code to give you an example but from memory - I think you get a "scroll" event fired at the end of a momentum scroll. Failing that, you could probably fire some code on touchEnd which, because no code will execute while the momentum scroll is happening, might fire at the end of the scroll.